# Confusion about the uniqueness (up to isomorphism) of $(\Bbb R,<)$

Tags: proof-explanation, order-theory

This theorem is from textbook *Introduction to Set Theory by Karel Hrbacek and Thomas Jech*

---

> **5.7 Theorem** $(\Bbb R,<)$ is the unique (up to isomorphism) complete linearly 
>   ordered set without endpoints that has a countable subset dense in it.
>
> *Proof.* Let $(C, \prec)$ be a complete linearly ordered set without endpoints, and let $P$ be a countable subset of $C$ dense in $C$. Then $(P, \prec)$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb Q, <)$ and by the uniqueness of completion (Theorem 5.3), $(C, \prec)$ is isomorphic to the completion of $(\Bbb Q, <)$, i.e., to $(\Bbb R,<)$.

---

First, let me present relevant theorems that lead to the above theorem.

1. Let $(P,<)$ and $(Q,\prec)$ be countable, dense, and linearly ordered sets without endpoints. Then  $(P,<)$ and $(Q,\prec)$ are order-isomorphic.
2. Let $(P, <)$ be a dense linearly ordered set without endpoints. Then there exists a complete linearly ordered set $(C,\prec)$ such that

(a) $P\subseteq C$.

(b) If $p,q\in P$ then $p < q$ if and only if $p \prec q$ ($<$ coincides with $\prec$ on $P$).

(c) $P$ is dense in $C$, i.e., for any $a,b\in C$ such that $a\prec b$, there is $p\in P$ with $a\prec p \prec b$.

(d) $C$ does not have endpoints.

Moreover, this complete linearly ordered set $(C,\prec)$ is unique up to isomorphism over $P$. In other words, if $(C^\ast,\prec^\ast)$ is a complete linearly ordered set which satisfies (a)-(d), then there is an isomorphism $h$ between $(C,\prec)$ and $(C^\ast,\prec^\ast)$ such that $h(x) = x$ for each $x \in P$. The linearly ordered set $(C,\prec)$ is called the completion of $(P, <)$.

---

My questions:

1. The proof of theorem 5.7 said that *let $P$ be a countable subset of $C$ dense in $C$. Then $(P, \prec)$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb Q, <)$*

But from (1), we can see that in order for  $(P, \prec)$ and $(\Bbb Q, <)$ to be isomorphic, $P, Q$ must be **countable, dense, linearly ordered, and without endpoints**. I'm unable to understand where in the proof *P* is mentioned to be dense ($P$ must be dense itself, not just dense in $C$), and without endpoints.

2. I think the authors use the following argument: $(\Bbb R,<)$ is the completion of $(\Bbb Q,<)$, $(C,\prec)$ is the completion of $(P,\prec)$, and $(\Bbb Q,<)$ and $(P,\prec)$ are isomorphic from (1). Then $(\Bbb R,<)$ and $(C,\prec)$ are isomorphic from (2).

I'm unable to understand why $(\Bbb R,<)$ and $(C,\prec)$ are isomorphic, please explain!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean when you say "$P$ must be dense itself, not just dense in $C$". You definition $(c)$ states that a set $A$ is dense in a set $C$. \\ Also, as $(C,\prec )$ is without endpoints and $P$ is dense in $C$, $P$ is without endpoints (if not $P$ can't be dense in $C$)

Comment: I suppose $(P,\prec)$ is dense "itself" means that for $p,q\in P$ there exists an $r\in P$ so that $p\prec r\prec q$ and then because $P\subseteq C$ "$P$ is dense in $C$" implies "$P$ is dense". The rest follows exactly as You explained

Comment: Yes, but as $P$ is dense in $C$, $P$ is dense in itself.

Comment: As $P \subseteq C$, for $p, q \in P \subseteq C$, $p, q \in C$ and there exist an $r \in P$ so that $p\prec r\prec q$ since $P$ is dense in $C$ by hypothesis. So $P$ is dense in itself.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much! Please address my question 2.!

Comment: The second part you got it right. Im going to use $P$ for $(P,\prec)$ and the same with the rest. For $(1)$ we have that $P$ and $\Bbb Q$ are isomorphic, and for (2), $C$ is the unique (up to isomorphism on $P$) completion of $P$. But then that means that any other isomorphic set of $P$ is going to have the same completion (up to isomorphism) and as $\Bbb Q$ and $P$ are isomorphic, the completion of $P$, $C$ is going to be isomorphic to the completion of $\Bbb Q$, $\Bbb R$ as we wanted to prove.

Comment: Hi @Alfredo! Please confirm If I understand your previous comment correctly! Since $P$ and $\Bbb Q$ are isomorphic, and $\Bbb R$ is the completion of $\Bbb Q$, we can define a completion $C'$ of $P$ from $P,\Bbb Q, \Bbb R$ such that $C'$ and $ \Bbb R$ are isomorphic. Since the completion of $P$ is unique up to isomorphism, $C$ and $C'$ are isomorphic. To sum up, we have that $C'$ and $\Bbb R$ are isomorphic and that $C$ and $C'$ are isomorphic. Hence $C$ and $\Bbb R$ are isomorphic.

Comment: Yes, that's completely right!

Comment: Thank you so much @Alfredo :)